# Drop a word in a column of data table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

I have a data table that looks like

```
            location                county
1:  40.96875_-72.78125      Walla Walla County
2:  41.15625_-90.65625           Mercer County
3:  41.21875_-90.65625           Mercer County
4:  41.28125_-89.84375           Bureau County
5:  41.28125_-89.90625            Henry County
```

How can I, efficiently, drop the word "county" in the `county` column, so, only the name of counties is left in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use de `gsub` function, replacing the word `"county"` with `""`:

```
df$county = gsub("county", "", df$county)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub` to select one or more spaces followed by characters that are not a space until the end (`$`) of the string, replace with blanks (`""`)

```
dt1[, county := sub("\\s+[^ ]+$", "", county)]
dt1$county
#[1] "Walla Walla" "Mercer"      "Mercer"      "Bureau"      "Henry"
```

If it is specific to 'County' word, then

```
dt1[, county := sub("\\s+County$", "", county)]
```